# How to fetch the data from two different tables for the multiple users all together?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 1 table for the user, 1 for comments and another for friends below is the table structure :

Comments Table :

```
------------------------------------------------
| comment_id  | user_id_c | commentstatus      | 
------------------------------------------------
|  1          |   1       |   Sample comment 1 |
|  2          |   2       |   Sample comment 2 |
------------------------------------------------
```

User Table :

```
------------------------------------------------------
| id  | username            | password  |  Full name |
------------------------------------------------------
|  1  |   user1 (loggedin)  | Sample 1  |  John      |
|  2  |   user2             | Sample 2  |  Smith     |
|  3  |   user3             | Sample 3  |  Andrew    |
|  4  |   user4             | Sample 4  |  Victor    |
|  3  |   user5             | Sample 3  |  Robert    |  
-------------------------------------------------------
```

Friends Tables

```
---------------------------------------------------
| id  | friend1             | friend2   |   status   
---------------------------------------------------
|  1  |   user1             | user3     |  friend
|  2  |   user1             | user5     |  friend
|  3  |   user2             | user4     |  friend
---------------------------------------------------
```

currently, if any user posts a comment it gets inserted there in the database inside comments table. now if I am logged in I can fetch all my comments from the database.

To explain I would like to inform that you all can see, user 1 is friend with user 3 and user 5 according to the friends table.

All I want is **to fetch the comments for the logged in user and for those who are the friend with the logged in user**. however, I am unable to figure it out that how can I fetch the comments of loggedin user and it's friends all together.

the script I am using to fetch my posts is as follows :

```
public function comments(){
            global $pdo;
            $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT u.*, c.* FROM users u INNER JOIN comments c ON u.id = c.user_id_c WHERE u.id = ".$_SESSION['sid']." ORDER BY c.comment_id DESC");
            $query->execute();
            return $query->fetchAll();
        }
```

and then fetching comments using below code :

```
$comments  = $get->comments();
```

Then :

```
foreach($comments as $row){

echo $row['Full name']; //user name from user table in the database
echo $row['commentstatus']; //comment from comments table in the database
```

It is fetching data for the logged in user perfectly, Is it possible anyway that I can fetch the comments from the friends of the logged in user also with logged in user's comments from the database at the same time.

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: the tables structures would help us out. As a side note, you're mixing prepared statements with normal ones.

Comment: I have updated my question and mentioned the table structure as well.

Comment: just a tip, it's usually way easier to write and test queries in a separate program like PHPMyAdmin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for something like this:

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT u.*, c.* FROM users u INNER JOIN comments c ON u.id = c.user_id_c WHERE u.id = ".$_SESSION['sid']." OR c.user_id IN (SELECT friend_id FROM friends WHERE friends.user_id = ".$_SESSION['sid'].") ORDER BY c.comments_id DESC"
```

Comment: This answer worked partially for me as when I mentioned the code like this : 

`$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT u.*, c.* FROM users u INNER JOIN comments c ON u.id = c.user_id_c WHERE u.id = 1 OR c.user_id_c IN (SELECT u.id FROM users WHERE id = 2) ORDER BY c.post_id DESC");`

However when I put variable at the place of '2' it doesn't work probably because the variable contains multiple user's ID. any suggestions..??